# Use delete glyphicon in Laravel 5 to delete a data

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hi need help in glyphicons with delete functionality.
These are my icons for update and delete. However, I only have my update working. I do not do with my delete. Please help! THanks a lot!

```
<a href='{{ url("admin/editTicket/$ticket->id") }}'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
```

Controller codes for update ticket:
where Chap_ticket is my database table name

```
public function editTicket($id)
{ 
    $tick = Chap_ticket::find($id);
    $tickets=Chap_ticket::all();
    return view('admin.registerTicket',compact('tick','tickets'));

}
```

My Route:

```
   Route::get('admin/editTicket/{id}','Admin\AdminController@editTicket');
   Route::get('admin/deleteTicket', 'AdminController@deleteTicket');
   Route::get('admin/registerTicket','Admin\AdminController@registerTicket');
```

Comment: You first need to make a delete action in one of your controllers or routes. Then you can refer to it in the same way as in the edit.

Comment: Here is my edit codes from my controller. How do I do  with my delete.. Just really new to Laravel. :( 
public function editUserType($id)
    { 
        $usertype = Chap_user_type::find($id);
        $user_types=Chap_user_type::all();
        return view('admin.registerUserType',compact('usertype','user_types'));

    }

Comment: THanks for answering

Comment: Please update your question with additional information rather than adding it as a comment. Also the code you've shared in the comment is not the `editTicket` code.

Comment: Thank you @apokryfos for the help in editing the question.. I am really new to Stack Overflow and new to programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new controller action like e.g. below:

```
public function deleteTicket($id) { 
    $tick = Chap_ticket::find($id);
    $tick->delete(); 
    return Redirect::back()->with('msg', 'Ticket deleted'); 
}
```

You may need to associate the new action with a route so you can add the following in your routes:

```
Route::get('admin/deleteTicket/{id}', 'Admin\AdminController@deleteTicket');
```

Assuming your controller is called `AdminController`

And in your view:

```
@if (isset($msg))
    <div>
       {{$msg}}
    </div>
@endif

<a href='{{ url("admin/editTicket/$ticket->id") }}'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
<a href="{{ url("admin/deleteTicket/$ticket->id") }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
```

This is based on the assumption that your view is a general admin page which will still be valid to when the ticket is deleted.

Comment: Thank you! this has been of great help. How will my routes look like? :) THank you thank you!

Comment: The route definition for the delete action will look a lot like the one for the edit action. The typical syntax is `Route::get("path/to/route", "Controller@method")`. There's more information in https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing and https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers

Comment: Thank u! I think i am doing it in a wrong way :( .I tried using your suggested route..  it shows that an error NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161.. I also used the one with Route::get('admin/deleteTicket/{id}', 'AdminController@deleteTicket');

Comment: What's the name of your controller? I've put the name `AdminController` there because I assumed, but wasn't sure.

Comment: Can you share a bit more from your routes?

Comment: Oh okay. sorry. There, I updated my question. I included my routes

Comment: Updated the answer, hadn't realised your controller was in a sub-folder.

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much!!! It did work!!! :) You saved me! Thank you. I also did not noticed what I'm missing!

Comment: Your controller is `Admin\AdminController` (i.e. it's in sub-directory `Admin`) so you have to specify this when you define the route otherwise laravel won't be able to find it and `AdminController` on its own wont work.

Comment: Yes. Thank you! I will make sure to keep that in mind.:) Thank you. I can now do basic CRUD on my application. Really new to Laravel and the programming world. :) Youre my saviour!